# UiPath Chrome Browser Connection Issue

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-robot

I have recently started using UiPath for our Automation.
Currently I am running this automation from Studio only and there is no orchestration.

My automation works fine for some time and fails most of the time with below error

```
 [Error] Failed executionUiPath.Core.BrowserOperationException: Cannot communicate with the browser, please check the UiPath extension. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot communicate with the browser, please check the UiPath extension.
   at UiPath.UiBrowserClass.Open(String bstrURL, String bstrCmdLineArgs, UiBrowserFlags flag)
   at UiPath.Core.Browser.Open(String url, CommMethod startBrowserMechanism, Boolean privateSession, Boolean headlessSession, Boolean defaultSession, String cmdLineArgs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at UiPath.Core.Activities.ScopeActivity.EndExecute(NativeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at UiPath.Core.Activities.ObsoleteAsyncNativeActivity.BookmarkResumptionCallback(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, Object value)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.BookmarkCallbackWrapper.Invoke(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, Object value)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.BookmarkWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

My automation is connecting to 4-5 different sites. works fine for 1-2 and then fails. if i run them 1 by 1 then all are getting passed.

Please suggest what can be the issue and how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official instructions to troublshoot. You didn't mention which browser, so here they all are: [Chrome](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/chrome-extension), [Firefox](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/firefox-extension), [Edge](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/microsoft-edge-extension-troubleshooting).

Essentially there's several things that could be wrong:

- Your UiPath extension isn't installed on the browser, or you didn't enable it, or you haven't configured it to "Allow in incognito". Follow the instructions for installing ([Chrome](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/extension-for-chrome), [Firefox](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/extension-for-firefox), [Edge](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/extension-for-edge-chromium)).
- You opened more than one browser session or profile for a given browser type (example: two different Chrome accounts). Try closing all browser windows and killing Chrome/Edge/etc. from Task Manager.
- There is a problem with your environment, group policy, or security policy.